# when using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle to send notifications daily, it works only one day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

when I use AlarmManager.SetRepeating () to send notifications two times daily it works fine for api<23
in api23 and above it doesn't send any notification so I use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23
it worked only the first day and stopped after that

```
public void OnRepeatingNotification() {
    String ACTION_ONE = "android.intent.action.ACTION_ONE";
    String ACTION_TWO = "android.intent.action.ACTION_TWO";
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    String content1 = getResources().getString(R.string.alarmone);
    String content2 = getResources().getString(R.string.alarmtwo);
    boolean sound=settings.getBoolean("sett_1",false);
    boolean vibrate=settings.getBoolean("sett_2",false);
    String[] parts = getTimes();
    String sunriseTime = parts[0].substring(0, 5) + " " + parts[0].substring(5);
    String[] sunriseTimeArray = sunriseTime.split(" ");
    String[] sunriseDivision = sunriseTimeArray[0].split(":");
    String sunsetTime = parts[1].substring(0, 5) + " " + parts[1].substring(5);
    String[] sunsetTimeArray = sunsetTime.split(" ");
    String[] sunsetDivision = sunsetTimeArray[0].split(":");
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReciever.class);
    myIntent.setAction(ACTION_ONE);
    myIntent.putExtra("title", title);
    myIntent.putExtra("content1", content1);
    myIntent.putExtra("sound",sound);
    myIntent.putExtra("vibrate",vibrate);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1253, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sunriseDivision[1]));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    //AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    pendingIntent);
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, NotificationReciever.class);
    myIntent2.setAction(ACTION_TWO);
    myIntent2.putExtra("title", title);
    myIntent2.putExtra("content2", content2);
    myIntent2.putExtra("sound",sound);
    myIntent2.putExtra("vibrate",vibrate);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1263, myIntent2,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // Set the time for second alarm here
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h2);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sunsetDivision[1]));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    //AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);

    AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle( alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent2 );
}
```

code of broadcast receiver to send notifications

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String content1 = intent.getStringExtra("content1");
        String content2 = intent.getStringExtra("content2");
        boolean vibrate = intent.getBooleanExtra("vibrate", false);
        boolean sound = intent.getBooleanExtra("sound", false);
        NotificationID n=new NotificationID();
       int NOTIFICATION_ID = n.getID();
        Intent in = new Intent(context, DailyAzkaar.class);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //If on Oreo then notification required a notification channel.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", "Default", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"default");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        if (vibrate == true)
            builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        if (sound == true) {
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        }
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.ACTION_ONE")) {
            in.putExtra("activity", 1);
            in.putExtra("poss", 0);// new
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1253, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            builder.setContentText(content1);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
        } else {
            in.putExtra("activity", 2);
            in.putExtra("poss", 0);// new
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1263, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            builder.setContentText(content2);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);

        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        //int notificationID = 0;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

Comment: If my answer does not work add the code for your repeating functionality and your broadcast receiver for more specific details to hel find a solution.

Comment: IMO make a test project and just schedule an alarm for every two minutes and test some scenarios. Play with actions and flags and debug the project until you get something out of it. Your code has so many complexities that makes it hard to help you from this point of view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Instead of checking for api versions to use the methods of AlarmManager you can use `AlarmManagerCompat`:

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
     @NonNull AlarmManager alarmManager, 
     int type,
     long triggerAtMillis, 
     @NonNull PendingIntent operation
)
```

Then try to set different actions and request code for your intents. You can use your time in milliseconds for actions and request code like so:

```
myIntent.setAction(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

and for pending intent change request code and flag to `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. So you can do:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, cal.getTimeInMillis(), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: why I use myIntent.setAction(cal.getTimeInMillis());
I put these actions in manifest.xml                                                                                          <receiver android:name=".NotificationReciever">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_ONE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TWO" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I Updated my question with the code of broadcast receiver